# Filter a list of persons by age and write the results to a relevant file

Tags: c#, object-oriented

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Data(string name, string lastname, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        LastName = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

I want to get the age of a person, if it's <18 then print all the data to Kids.csv, else I want it to be printed to Adults.csv.

I know it's simple and I managed to do that, but the teacher said that my code didn't look like objective programming. He told me that I need to use method to return array and create other method for writing the array to file or something.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        People[] people = new People[MaxPeople];
        people = ReadData();

        WriteKids(people);
        WriteAdults(people);
    }




static void WriteKids(Data[] people)
{
File.WriteAllText(@"Kids.csv", String.Empty);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Kids.csv", true, Encoding.Default))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        if (people[i].Age < 18)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("{0};{1};{2}", people[i].Name,              people[i].LastName, people[i].Age);
        }
    }
}


static void WriteAdults(Data[] people)
{
        File.WriteAllText(@"Adults.csv", String.Empty);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Adults.csv", true, Encoding.Default))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                if (people[i].Age => 18)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("{0};{1};{2}", people[i].Name, people[i].LastName, people[i].Age);
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Have you already been graded on this or are you trying to get us to do your homework?

Comment: wait, is this really the same as https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105530/write-object-data-to-csv-files

Answer (score 6):

- Why is your class called `Data`? It's obviously a `Person`.
- In compound words like `lastname` each "part" needs to be capitalized, so it should be `lastName`. You did this correctly with `LastName`, so be consistent.
- What is `People[]`? A collection of `People`s? No, it's a collection of `Person`s. Also, you didn't provide us with the code for `People`, not the code for `ReadData();`.
- Why define something -- `People[] people = new People[MaxPeople];` -- and then assign it a value on the next line -- `people = ReadData();`? Combine the two lines.
- Why do you use `for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)` and not `foreach`?

---

Why do `File.WriteAllText(@"Kids.csv", String.Empty);` and `File.WriteAllText(@"Adults.csv", String.Empty);`? [`StreamWriter` will create the file if it doesn't exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt.aspx)

Do you want to clear the file in case it exists? Then use `false` instead of `true` for the `bool append` parameter of your `StreamWriter` constructor.

Matter of fact, considering you're using the default encoding and considering you're overwriting the existing contents if the file exists, why not use [a simpler constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx)?

---

`WriteKids` and `WriteAdults` do basically the same thing, except for the logic in the `if` and the filename. So they're candidates to be replaced by a  single method that accepts these as parameter.

Of course, the `if` logic is hard to represent as a parameter, so that's an indication you've done something wrong. What if the `if` logic was simply a `bool`, `isAnAdult`? That would make it easier.

So the question is: how can you compare something against that bool? The solution: add a (read-only) `IsAnAdult` property to the `Person` class, which returns the result of `Age > 18`.

Of course, I'm again combining things when your teacher told you:

> He told me that I need to use method to return array and create other
>   method for writing the array to file or something.

So you should have:

- one method that accepts `Person[]` and a `bool isAnAdult` as parameters and returns `Person[]` for which `isAnAdult` is true or false,
- a second method that accepts this filtered `Person[]` and a filename and creates the file.

Comment: Good post, except for one thing: the `if` logic is actually easy to represent as a parameter: a predicate with type `Func<Person, bool>`. For children, you'd pass in a lambda expression like `person => person.Age < 18`.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Yes, I know, but this is obviously someone who's just starting out. Considering he still uses arrays and not `IEnumerable<T>`, I doubt he'll know about lambda expressions.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with your teacher that you should have the print method do as little else as possible.  You should try to have methods that do only one thing because they are easier to read and test.  Another thing is to keep your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).  If you have code that is repeated, you should refactor it into a separate method.  So you have two reasons to print the results in a separate method.  Also, you can replace the loops with LINQ, which is more concise, safer, and easier to read in my opinion.  I prefer to explicitly declare whether each method is public or private.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    People[] people = new People[MaxPeople];
    people = ReadData();

    var kids = GetKids(people);
    var adults = GetAdults(people);
    WritePeople(kids, @"Kids.csv");
    WritePeople(adults, @"Adults.csv");
}

private static Data[] GetKids(Data[] people)
{
    return people.Where(x => x.Age < 18).ToArray();
}

private static Data[] GetAdults(Data[] people)
{
    return people.Where(x => x.Age >= 18).ToArray();
}

private static void WritePeople(Data[] people, string fileName)
{
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, String.Empty);    
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true, Encoding.Default))
    {
        foreach(var person in people)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("{0};{1};{2}", person.Name, person.LastName, person.Age);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why is the class named Data if you call them People? (not familar with C#, this may not be an issue?)

WriteAdults and WriteKids should be a function inside your class

```
static void writeKids(StreamWriter writer, string fileName){ }

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
     people[i].writeKids(...);
}
```